# Does Object class also extends some other class?

Tags: java, oop, object

Every Class in java extends Object class. Does Object class also extends some other class?

Comment: No. Object is the base of all.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Object class also extends some other class?

No. It is the first class in the hierarchy.

Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

> Class Object is the **root of the class hierarchy**. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

Answer (score 0):

no it is the first defined object in the hierarchy, you can see the hierarchy on the Object.java api.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: I disagree. java.lang is the package and not a base class!

Comment: that way my bad wording, sorry I meant that the only thing above it is the package itself.